# Some problems of Python crawler

Tags: python, ajax, post, httpfox

And I'm just suffering from the question about python crawler.

First, the websites have two different hexadecimal of Chinese chracters. I can convert one of them (which is E4BDA0E5A5BD), the other one is C4E3BAC3 which I have no method to convert, or maybe I am missing some methods. The two hexadecimal values are '你好' in Chinese.

Second, I have found a website which can convert the hexadecimal, and to my surprise the answer is exactly what I cannot covert by myself.

The url is http://www.uol123.com/hantohex.html

Then I made a question: how to get the result which is in the text box (well I don't know what it is called exactly). I used firefox + httpfox to observe the post's data, and I find that the result which is converted by the website is in the Content, here is the pic:

And then I print the post, it has POST Data, and some headers, but no info about Content.

Third, then I google how to use ajax, and I really found a code about how to use ajax.

Here is the url http://outofmemory.cn/code-snippet/1885/python-moni-ajax-request-get-ajax-request-response
But when I run this, it has an error which says "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded."

And pardon that I am a newbie, so I cannot post images!!!

I am looking forward to your help sincerely.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you supply the url to the website you're trying to read?

Comment: If you cannot post images, then maybe you should remove the reference to a picture that is not there ?

Comment: Furthermore, it is really difficult to follow what you are asking exactly.  Could you please rephrase the question into a clearly stated question, like: How do you parse these two Chinese symbols out of a website's Content?

Answer (score 0):

you're talking about different encodings for these chinese characters. there are at least three different widely used encodings `guobiao` (for mainland China), `big5` (on Taiwan) and `unicode` (everywhere else).

here's how to convert your kanji into the different encodings:

```
>>> a = u'你好'             -- your original characters
>>> a
u'\u4f60\u597d'            -- in unicode
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd' -- in UTF-8
>>> a.encode('big5')
'\xa7A\xa6n'               -- in Taiwanese Big5
>>> a.encode('gb2312-80')
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'         -- in Guobiao
>>>
```

You may check other available encodings [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Ah, almost forgot. to convert from Unicode into the encoding you use `encode()` method. to convert back from the encoded contents of the web site you may use `decode()` method. just don't forget to specify the correct encoding.

Comment: well, I can command the first two whose results are different from yours,but there are errers in the last two.                       >>> a=u'你好'                                                      >>> a
u'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\x84\xc3\xa3\xc2\xba\xc3\x83'

Comment: u'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3' is not unicode, it's some kind of windows wncoding, most likely Guobiao (see above, it is same), you should do something like: `a = '你好'.decode('gb2312-80')` to get a **REAL** unicode.